# Should I repeat "to be" with nouns

Tags: grammar

In the following sentence I am not sure whether I have to repeat the verb "to be" twice with the Past Participle.

> A card that **is** provided to clients and **(is)** managed by a concierge team.

The same problem when it is Preset Continuous tense and the subject has two or more actions in the sentence. 
Actually I face similar problem with all sentences with not only one action and the tense form supposes using an auxiliary.

Comment: In general, _if_ there is no possibility the sentence can be misinterpreted, you can leave the second "is" out safely. But in this particular example, leaving it out makes the sentence almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is valid, technically speaking.

In practice, if the sentence says a lot between the first and second places where you could put the "is", then you would include the second "is" to make the sentence easier to read, but if the sentence is quite short you might omit the second one to keep it concise.

In some cases, omitting the second "is" can lead to ambiguity. For example, what happens if I interpret the sentence like this:

> A card that is [provided to clients and managed] by a concierge team.

If the card is provided to clients by someone who is not the concierge team, this might be be misleading, because when structured like this, the sentence could be interpreted to mean that the concierge team does both things. You could resolve this by putting a comma after "clients", but adding that second "is" makes it clearer. (The comma would depend on your writing style; this is effectively a list of things that happens to cards, so this would count as an [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma)).